# How to find roots of $\sin (x) - a$?

Tags: trigonometry, roots

How to find roots of $\sin(x) - a$, where $a \in [0, 1)$ and $x \in [0, 2\pi]$?

Comment: with $x=\arcsin a$

Comment: Heard of the $arcsin$ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The roots are $\arcsin(a)$ and $\pi - \arcsin(a)$.

Answer (score 0):

The inverse function for $\sin $ is called arcsinus and noted $\arcsin x$. More on this function [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions).

Answer (score 0):

$$x=k\pi+(-1)^k\sin^{-1}{(a)}$$ so when $k$ is even, it is $k\pi+\sin^{-1}{(a)}$, and when $k$ is odd, it is $k\pi-\sin^{-1}{(a)}$